# Drupal 7 : How do I give permission access for an user with a defined role ?

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-7, roles

I have 2 roles: *administrator* and *webmaster*.
I added diverse permissions in a module custom. Then in "admin/people/permissions" I authorize the access to a permission for a role.

I would like authorize the access to a permission, not for a role, but for a user with a defined role.

More exactly: I wish that the role *administrator* can authorize, or not, the access to a permission for each user with the role webmaster.

Is there any module for achieving this ?

How can I realise this ?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/node_access

Comment: NodeAccess and FlexiAccess do not correspond. I need to authorize access to a permission stemming from a custom module, for each user (with a role webmaster)

Comment: check out OG module https://www.drupal.org/project/og and http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!og!og.module/7, or develop custom module to achieve exactly what you want

Comment: thanks. I developed a custom module !